# Rx tableView only gives me last value in cell despite there being numerous data objects

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, rx-swift

I have an `RxTableView` that is binding data from a `relay`. When I check the data before `binding` it, I get around 10 data objects, but the `tableView` `cell` only display the last one.

In my `viewModel` I have a reload `method`:

```
var bufferEvent = ReplaySubject<EventModel>.create(bufferSize: 99)
let content = BehaviorRelay<[EventStatusTableViewCellViewModel]>(value: [])


func reloadTableViewContent() -> Observable<EventModel> {
    return eventService.bufferEvent.do(onNext: { event in
        print("THIS RETURNS 8 OBJECTS", event.id)
        self.content.accept([EventStatusTableViewCellViewModel(eventStatus: event)])
    })
}
```

The print returns 8 objects.
In my `viewController` I call `viewModel.reloadTableViewContent().subscribe().disposed(by: diposeBag)`

and set the `bindings`:

```
private func setBindings() {
    print("THIS IS ZERO", viewModel.content.value.count)

    viewModel.content.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: EventLogTableViewCell.identifier, cellType: EventLogTableViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
        cell.viewModel = data
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

The `tableView` only shows the very last object, but ignores the rest for some reason.

Why doesn't this work? Let me know if there is additional code I need to show, like the `cell` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

1.Do not need function reloadTableViewContent(), you are think RX in a imperative way.Instead,just bind those two subjects once and no need to worry about the rest because they are reactive and responsive.

2.Notice `.toArray()` ,you forgot to collect your element to make it an array.

```
eventService.bufferEvent.toArray().asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: []).drive(content)
```